# What would carbon-oxygen polymer be called?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecules

So I have a chain molecule made of carbon and oxygen, and I'm not sure what it would be called. Would any of you lovely fellows be able to help me?

[image: molecule drawn badly on paint]

The best name I've been able to come up with so far is "polyquadcarboxate" but I'm pretty sure this isn't right.

I'm looking for an IUPAC name if possible, but I suppose other names will do.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Carbon dioxide. (Because that is what it would degrade to, give it a femtosecond.)

Comment: I'm looking for the name of the molecule itself, not what it would decompose to. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Giving names to non-existing entities is not IUPAC's primary interest.

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_carbonia - CO2 polymerises at very high pressures, but creates 3D not linear structure

Comment: @querambique your compound could be called linear polymeric carbon dioxide

Answer (score 1):

The generic name is *[oxocarbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxocarbon)*. In particular, "Carbon suboxide spontaneously polymerizes at room temperature into a carbon-oxygen polymer, with 3:2 carbon:oxygen atomic ratio." This is not quite the formula you provide, but the polymer has been synthesized.